# Selecting all elements from XML documents having no attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

I am bit stuck trying to select all elements of XML documents using XPath expression which give me all elements except those elements having no attributes.

I tried XPath expression below

```
//book[not(@*)]
```

but this is only working with book elements.  How do I make it for whole XML document?

**Update/clarification:**

```
<root>
  <node lang="eng"> Hello how r u </node>
  <node lang = "urdu">mera dost </node>
  <node lang ="itally">chayoo chayoo  </node>
  <node>  shukria  </node>
  <items>
    <item> first item </item>
    <item type="Green"> second item</item>
  </items>
  <values price = "very low"> Price </values>
  <values> normal price</values>
  <values price= "very hight"> H price </values>
</root>
```

I tried with `//*[not(@*)]` but this XPath expression is selecting `<items>` element as well which also contains `<item type= "Green">second item </item>`.  How should I avoid this?

Comment: Replace `book` with `*`

Comment: First of all make your XML-fragment well-formed before testing.... if you have already done so then please elaborate a bit your problem with  examples, so that we could understand that properly. «//*[not(@*)]» is the only solution, if not then please write a bit more....

Comment: try then `«//*[not(@*) and not(*[@*])]»`...

Answer (score 1):

`//` can be used to select any descendant; `*` can be used to select any element; and `@*` can select any attribute, so:

```
//*[not(@*)]
```

**Update per OP's update:**

To exclude descendant elements that have attributes:

```
//*[not(@*) and not(.//*[@*])]
```

So, for your given XML, only the following nodes would be selected:

```
<node>shukria</node>
<item>first item</item>
<values>normal price</values>
```

as requested.